# Inserting an Image in Header Behind Navigation Menu | Tesseract Theme

Tags: css, wordpress

ORIGINAL POST 11/26/17:

I'm new to coding, and am having trouble inserting a background image. I'd like to display it behind the top navigation menu, across the full width of the screen. I'm using the Tesseract Theme in WordPress, and inserted the code to do this under "Additional CSS". Here's what I have so far (I changed the image URL here for privacy, though the webpage CSS contains the real URL):

```
body { 
background: #f8f8f8 
url(http://examplewebsite.com/imagename.jpeg) 
repeat-x top; 
background-size: 1920px 100px; }
```

The parts I'm having trouble figuring out is (1) how to properly scale/crop the image (since it's stretched now), and (2) how to get the image to lock to the top of the page behind the navigation menu, and disappear with the menu once you scroll down the page.

I know I probably have to fix several things, so I appreciate the help!

EDIT (11/28/17):

How does this new code look? The picture actually stretches now to the whole page, instead of just staying in the header, behind the navigation menu on the top. I think I wrote the "div" wrong.

```
body { 
background: #f8f8f8 
url(http://examplewebsite.com/imagename.jpeg) 
repeat-x top; 
background-size: cover;}
div {position:absolute}
```

Comment: please share your website link. so we can check.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "background-size: cover" or "background-size: contain" and also don't use background in the body, just define new div in and give it "position:absolute"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed "background-size:1920px 100px;" to "background-size: cover," but I'm not sure how to define a new "div". I edited my original post with the updated code. 

I'm pretty sure I still did something wrong; the picture now stretches the whole page, instead of just staying in the header, behind the navigation menu on the top. 

I also tried deleting “background: #f8f8f8”, but it gives me the error “expected RBRACE”.

Answer (score 0):

Into **Tesseract Designer Theme** you can easily do this by using Header Layout Background Image. 
Avail this option from, 
**Appearance -> Customize -> Header options -> Header Layout -> Header Layout Background Image.** 
Choose the image, and also you get the option of **Image repeat Enable / Disable**. 
Don't forgot the theme name **Tesseract Designer Theme** to solve your problem.

Thanks